# Mobile Qt Application missing in Qt Creator 2.5.2

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

On the new **Qt Creator 2.5.2**, I no longer see the option to create a **Mobile Qt Application** when starting a New Project.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, and I installed Qt Creator from the repositories.

[image]

This is what I see on **Qt Creator 2.4.1**. This here is on Windows, but Mobile Qt Application used to be available on Ubuntu as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options appear in the Creator that comes bundled with Nokia's Qt SDK (and yes that contains an older version of Qt Creator and desktop and mobile Qt framework), you can download that from [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html)

Comment: Did they decide to remove the Mobile Qt Application from newer versions of Qt Creator?

Comment: It's not really a removal, it actually was an addition to the Creator made by Nokia for the Qt SDK provided for their phones with Symbian and Meego, so those are Nokia's tools, and only their SDK has Qt built for mobile phones and those "application templates" in Creator (and the Symbian/Meego simulator and other tools for phones)

Comment: But I remember Qt Creator used to have it on Ubuntu, too.

Comment: In the link i gave you i my first post you can download Nokia's sdk for linux too, that is probably what you had installed.